# Neo4jServer locking DB and getting an exception org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Could not create lock file

Tags: neo4j

**help me out to resolve this issue 
I am creating the Db though this code**

Creating The Database

```
    graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {

        /* creating app node and setting properties of the node */
        app = graphDb.createNode();
        appNodeId = app.getId();
        System.out.println("AppNodeId:::::::::::" + appNodeId);
        app.setProperty("appId", appPojo.getAppId());
        app.setProperty("appName", appPojo.getAppName());
        // app.setProperty("userList", appPojo.getUserList());
        System.out.println(">>>>app_data" + app.getId());

        /* creating user node and setting properties of the node */
        user = graphDb.createNode();
        user.setProperty("userId", userPojo.getUserId());
        user.setProperty("userName", userPojo.getUserName());
        user.setProperty("appId", appPojo.getAppId());
        System.out.println(">>>>user_data" + user.getId());

        /* creating HAS_A relationship between app node and user node */
        relationship = app.createRelationshipTo(user, RelTypes.HAS_A)

    }

    finally {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>Finally");
    }
```

DB_PATH is my local directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your database a lock file is created. If you don't shut it down properly the lock file is not removed. When you start it again, the lock file already exists, can't be created, and an exception is thrown. Try manually removing the lock file from `DB_PATH` and make sure that next time you shut down the db properly; you should have an explicit call to `graphDb.shutdown()` for the ordinary case and a shutdown hook for the exceptional case. This is what the shutdown hook looks like in the Neo4j example code

```java
private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb ) 
{
   Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            graphDb.shutdown();
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: or use try { } finally { graphDb.shutdown(); } if you do only a one-time activity with your database files.